# IntelliJ / PyCharm — bind minus key to change current code pane (buffer) to display directory list

Tags: python, intellij-idea, vim, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Any way to have Vim-style netrw file exploration in the code pane in an IDEA IDE (IntelliJ, PyCharm)?

I want to hit the <kbd>-</kbd> (minus) key and then have a in-buffer directory listing show up from which I can use `h`, `i`, `j`, `k` to select files, move around directories, like in netrw of Vim.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no feature in IntelliJ or PyCharm for showing the directory list in an editor window. You can use the navigation bar, which should give you a similar keyboard navigation experience.

Comment: navigation bar mode “search pattern amongst files” (Ctrl+Shift+‘n’, I think) works great for IntelliJ, because Java classes you want tend to be nested from project root dir.  But for python / data-science projects, we often want to search for files outside of the project root (one or two levels up).  How to make “search amongst files” navigation bar do this?  Feel free to post as the solution and I will gladly accept. Thanks

Comment: @ppp Does PyCharm / IntelliJ has some "external references" sort of functionality? I mean: in PhpStorm it's called [PHP Include Paths](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-include-paths.html) where you can reference any 3rd party library (folder) and it will be indexed by IDE and therefore you can navigate there using that `Navigate | File (Ctrl+Shift+N)` popup.

Comment: **P.S.** One thing that exists for sure in any IDEA-based IDE is the ability to add Additional Content Roots (will show such folder as an additional node in the Project View / will treat it as part of the project): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-content-roots.html

Comment: @LazyOne thanks for the tips on additional project roots. I haven’t looked into it for PyCharm, but I did contact official help and their suggestion was to just use the Searching Functionality (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/searching-everywhere.html)  and bind it to a key, then use it as you would with Navigation-Bar-Mode-Files-Search (Ctrl+Shift+N)